# Unable to handle password notification in Google Chrome

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium

I'm using the following code, but unable to handle password notification (in Google Chrome):

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
//options.setExperimentalOption("credentials_enable_service", false);
options.setExperimentalOption("profile.password_manager_enabled", false);

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\Prashant\\Downloads\\chromedriver.exe");
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Error Message-

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException:
>   unknown error: cannot parse capability: chromeOptions from unknown
>   error: unrecognized chrome option: profile.password_manager_enabled.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot parse capability: chromeOptions
from unknown error: unrecognized chrome option: profile.password_manager_enabled.


Above is the error message

Comment: May I know why you need to set options? If you disable it then it should work.

Comment: I tried it your way. But it didn't work. I googled ways to disable notification and found above mentioned code where I need to pass ChromeOption object while instantiating ChromeDriver, still I my target is not achieved

Answer (score 0):

While working with `Selenium 3.x`, `chromedriver v2.31` and `Google Chrome 60.x`, you can consider to use the **`Map`** interface & cast it to **`HashMap`** to set the arguments **`credentials_enable_service`** and **`profile.password_manager_enabled`** both to **`false`** as follows:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;        

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
prefs.put("credentials_enable_service", false);
prefs.put("profile.password_manager_enabled", false);
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
options.addArguments("start-maximized");
options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.navigate().to("https://google.com");
```